# Use lenskit to recommend for user not in dataset

Tags: lenskit

I try lenskit to build a recommendation system but in tutorial I only can get recommmend for user in dataset. I want to build a model and get recommend for a user that send an array of what he like. How can I do that?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LensKit requires the data set to contain your users' data, unless you use the item-based recommenders/scorers.  However, model training and recommendation/prediction can use different data sets - LensKit just assumes that you've stored user preferences in LensKIt's database before generating predictions.

Some algorithms (e.g. FunkSVD) ignore user data that isn't in the model. Others (item-item and user-user) make use of current user data in the data access object.